# Issue to Update HTML Table after Data Insert using Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datatables

I am new to `Ajax`.I tried to update my `HTML table` after successfully insert of data in database using `Ajax` instead of loading the entire form by using `window.location.reload()`.

**Insert Method**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveUser(Employee objEmployee)  //Employee is the class
{
      //My Code for insert
}
```

This works fine as the data inserts successfully.`Ajax` insert defined below

**Update Method**

```
public static void GetData()  //Tried using datatable as return type nothing happened
{
    //var dt = new DataTable();
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(Constr))
    {
        const string query = "select * from TblUser";
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (TableData)
                {
                    sda.Fill(TableData);
                    //return TableData;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On button save my `ajax` script is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            alert("TESST");
            var user = {};
            user.FName = $("#FirstName").val();
            user.LName = $("#Surname").val();
            user.MName = $("#MiddleName").val();
            // Some others are also there
            user.CreatedDateTime = new Date();
            user.ModifiedDateTime = new Date();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/SaveUser",
                data: '{objEmployee: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function () {
                    alert("User has been added successfully.");
                    //Another Ajax to update the grid
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
                        data: "{}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function () {
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Error while Showing update data");
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error while inserting data");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have binded to HTML Table like this

```
<table id="dataTables-example" role="grid">
<thead>
   <tr role="row">
      <th>Name</th>
       <th>Email Id</th>
       <th>Mobile(H)</th>
       <th >Mobile(O)</th>
       <th>Joining Date</th>
       <th>Birth Date</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <% for (var data = 0; data < TableData.Rows.Count; data++)
     { %>
       <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
        <td class="sorting_1"><%=TableData.Rows[data]["FName"]%></td>
        <td><%=TableData.Rows[data]["EMail"]%></td>
        <td><%=TableData.Rows[data]["Telephone"]%></td>
        <td><%=TableData.Rows[data]["Mobile"]%></td>
        <td><%=TableData.Rows[data]["DOJ"]%></td>
        <td><%=TableData.Rows[data]["DOB"]%></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**My Issues**

> 1. My update method is called after insert but I am not able to see the updated data.
> 2. After page refresh as the `webmethod` is `static` multiple data shows.

Comment: In your ajax call to GetData, on success you haven't written any code? The data returned from server is not rebound to table right?

Comment: @Vignesh:Ahh thanks.Let me find a solution how to bind.

Answer (score 0):

Loop trough the received data and set them to your table :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
         for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
         $("#dataTables-example tbody").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].FName+ " 
         </td><td>" + data.d[i].EMail+ "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Telephone+ "
         </td></tr>");
         }
         },
        error: function () {
        alert("Error while Showing update data");
        }
        });
```

Comment: Am sorry its not working.Again I am not able to write my class for styles in <tr>.
My second issue is still there.

Comment: [Check out this](http://www.codescratcher.com/jquery/bind-data-to-gridview-with-jquery-json-asp-net/)